# it is acceptable to violate a rule of normalization in favor of performance?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

i have a db with a table 'product' in relation with a table 'discount'.
the discount table, in turn, is in relation with 'brand' and 'category'.
i need to know the 'calculatedPrice' of each product and than sort them (about 30.000 products).
but, in this way, the query is too slow.
it is acceptable to violate the 3rd rule of normalization, and add 'calculatedPrice' as a column in db?
the column will than be calculated by a query run once every 5 min or so...
i don't see any other solution.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. However, I suggest you reread the rationale for those "rules". Reason is that if you break the rules, you also lose the advantages you gain from them.

Comment: The topic is "denormalization". Also, your question is a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should this information be calculated in real time or stored in a seperate database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376567/should-this-information-be-calculated-in-real-time-or-stored-in-a-seperate-datab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on your situation: for example, I had a table once which contained the information to generate an invoice, such as the price, but also the VAT value at the time of invoice's emission.

The VAT Value changes overtime, but it cannot influence previously emitted invoices, so the only way to avoid problems was to store the value itself rather than a reference on a "constant values" table. This, indeed, produces redundancy of the information inside the table and possible "inconsistencies" inside the database.

That said, I would consider very carefully the reasons behind your choice of adding a column (note that these are just to make you think, not pointing a finger anywhere :) ):

- are you sure that performances are affected by a couple of joins of your tables?
- if so, are you sure that the problem doesn't lie somewhere else in your design?
- do you always need the value of `calculatedPrice` for all your products or can you reduce the number of rows, calculating only the values for the products you actually need?

If your answer is "Yes" for all the questions above, then go for the extra column.

**P.S.**: I would, in any case, avoid things like having "a query run once every 5 min or so": this opens your system to synchronization problems, and concurrency issues. What would happen if the discount has changed, but your "update query" has not yet run? Would then your program retrieve an old value?